# Without using Franglais, how do you express "pom-pom girl" {cheerleader}?

Tags: expressions

> Le monde du travail semble donc se partager en deux : ceux qui promettent leur mutisme à leur employeur, et ceux qui, ***pom-pom girls de leur entreprise***, se sentent obligés de défendre tout ce qu’ils y font sur les réseaux sociaux.

It's safe to assume that the writer opted for Franglais here on purpose to pack some punch. But I wonder how you express this idea idiomatically without using Franglais, even at the cost of taking the edge off the comical effect, making it blander?

Comment: Well, *pom-pom girl* is not Franglais. It's a French word, just as much as as *croissant* is an English word. Nothing wrong using it in a French text since there is no other word to refer to this activity (at least in France). You can't change it without modifying the figurative comparison.

Comment: Let it be noted that is a regionalism specific to France.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The noun we use specifically for someone who will defend a person or a cause without restraint is *chantre*:

- ceux qui, **chantres** de leur entreprise,...

From Larousse: 
"Personne qui glorifie, loue quelqu'un ou quelque chose : *Il s'est fait le chantre du pouvoir.*"
(http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chantre/14658)

Some others suggestions as a complement:

- ceux qui, **voulant arborer les couleurs** de leur entreprise,...
- ceux qui, **porte-étendard** de leur entreprise,...

Distic's proposition of "avocats" or "porte-parole" is good, but in that case I'd use the idiomatic expression *se faisant les*:

- ceux qui, **se faisant les avocats** de leur entreprise,...

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with Baerrow on the comparison.

In this sentence, pom-pom girl is closer to someone who defends **excessively** the point of vue/spirit of their company.

But as pointed out in the comments, pom-pom girl is a correct french word, containing this idea of excessiveness.

Answer (score 2):

En anglais, la [*pompom girl*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pompom-girl) c'est une « female cheerleader, as for a football team, whose routines often include the waving of large flowerlike clusters or streamers resembling pompoms » (Dictionary.com; contra [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pompom%20girl) ; voir [pom-pom](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/pom-pom)/[pom-pon](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pompom&submit.x=0&submit.y=0), du [français](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pompom) [pompon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pompon)).
On peut expliquer la [*cheerleader*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/cheerleader/569662) comme une forme de [*majorette*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/majorette/48771?q=majorette#48686) (Larousse en ligne), entre autres. En français on a le pseudo-emprunt [pom-pom girl(s)](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pom-pom_girl/186636?q=pom%20pom#10928041) directement au lexique, contrairement à la *cheerleader* semble-t-il, pour la « jeune fille qui défile en agitant des pompons aux couleurs d'une équipe sportive, avant un match, une compétition » (Larousse en ligne). On trouve par ailleurs [*la meneuse ou le meneur de*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8362264) [claque](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26507244) ; la *claque* est une terme proposé par l'OQLF pour désigner l'équivalent du *cheerleading*, avec un sens englobant davantage que l'unique pratique en contexte sportif. Mais pour rester dans le contexte de la joute sportive, je comprendrais aussi la *mascotte* comme une référence colorée d'appartenance totale à l'équipe.

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce contexte, vous pouvez dire :

- "avocat", qui me plaît assez car il y a "défendre" dans la suite, et parce que les magistrats, avec leurs vêtements et leur cérémonial peuvent peut-être suggérer un effet analogue à celui qui est suggéré par les *pom-pom girls*.
- "porte-parole"
- "représentant"

Comment: "avocat" would sounds weird to me in that sentence. "porte-drapeau", "porte-étendard", "héraults" would fit.

Comment: I do not understand why. A "avocat" may have to speak for his client, he may have to defend him, and he may wear some funny clothes. I do not see why it could not be a better translation than "hérault" or "porte-étendard"...

Comment: I agree about the meaning, it just that "ceux qui, avocats de leur entreprise" really makes me believe that those people are actually working as lawyers (it is much more likely to be a company's lawyer than to be a company's pom pom girl or 'porte-étendard'). But I think we may well use the noun "avocat" if we reformulate a bit: "ceux qui, se faisant les avocats de leur entreprise,..." which is quite idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *pom-pom girls* refers to the behavior of the employees.

The author compares the employees to the cliché of the *pomp-pom girl*, who can't keep a secret and reveal all in social network.

This sens of this text is based on this comparison. Using other word would change all of it